# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer smooth orientation rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I'm trying to disable any discernable orientation rotation to an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer while still maintaining rotation for any subviews. AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer does have an orientation property, and changing it does allow for the layer to display properly for any orientation. However, the rotation involves some funky rotation of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, rather than staying smooth as it does in the Camera app.

This is how I've gotten orientation to work properly, minus the hitch in the rotation:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    _captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
}
```

How do I get this layer to act like the Camera app, while maintaining rotations for its subviews?

Also, as an aside, I've seen that the orientation property is depreciated on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, and the videoOrientation property of AVCaptureConnection should be used instead, but I don't think I have an AVCaptureConnection to access here (I'm simply displaying the camera on the screen). How should I set this up to access videoOrientation?

Answer (score 12):

Using an affine transform on the view containing the preview layer creates a smooth transition:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (cameraPreview) {
        if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            cameraPreview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        } else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            cameraPreview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
        } else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            cameraPreview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
        }
        cameraPreview.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }
}
```

The `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` function is called within the rotation animation block so changing properties here will animate along with the rest of the rotation animations. This function has been phased out in iOS 6 and replaced with new methods to handle device rotation, so this works for now, but isn't the best solution.

Comment: Xcode is telling me that I cannot use the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation method and that for my previewlayer I need to use the CATransform3DMakeRotation method. Is your code wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Will CGAffineTransformMakeRotation is for UIViews, CATransform3DMakeRotation is for CGLayers

Comment: `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is now deprecated. You can get the same result using `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` by assigning the transform/frame inside the animation block of `[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:completion:`.

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but since it didn't have an accepted answer and I've been dealing with this issue myself for the past several days, I figured I would post the answer.

The trick to rotating the video based on device orientation changes, is to **NOT ROTATE** the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` or the `AVCaptureConnection` at all.

Changing the orientation on the `AVCaptureConnection` ( `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`'s orientation was deprecated ) **ALWAYS** results in an ugly animated change .. And after the video is rotated, you would still have to transform the preview layer.

The correct way to do this is use an `AVAssetWriter` to write the Video and Audio data .. and then apply a transform on the `AVAssetWriterInput` at the time that you start recording.

Here is a blurb from Apple about this --

[Receiving rotated CVPixelBuffers from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/AudioVideo/RN-AVFoundation/_index.html)

> To request buffer rotation, a client calls -setVideoOrientation: on
>   the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput's video AVCaptureConnection. Note that
>   physically rotating buffers does come with a performance cost, so only
>   request rotation if it's necessary. **If, for instance, you want
>   rotated video written to a QuickTime movie file using AVAssetWriter,
>   it is preferable to set the -transform property on the
>   AVAssetWriterInput rather than physically rotate the buffers in
>   AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.**

The applying of the transform is similar to the code posted above.

1. You register for device orientation changes.
2. Keep track of transform to apply based on the new device orientation.
3. When record is pressed, set up the AVAssetWriterInput and apply transform to it.

Hope this helps whoever is looking for an answer.

Comment: Having a similar problem using 'setVideoOrientation' so appreciate the comment Kal. Now that I know the issue, are there any examples out there which show this in action? BTW, the referenced link no longer works. Try this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/releasenotes/AudioVideo/RN-AVFoundation/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010717-CH1-DontLinkElementID_12

Comment: Found an example and, not surprisingly, it was also from Kal. Here is the link: http://runkalrun.blogspot.com/2013/01/capturing-videos-on-iphone-and-rotating.html. Thanks Kal, great info!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this with the following code:

Set up when you need the camera:

```
preview = [[self videoPreviewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] retain];
[self.view addSubview:preview];
```

The `videoPreviewWithFrame` function.

```
- (UIView *) videoPreviewWithFrame:(CGRect) frame {
  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *tempPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[self captureSession]];
  [tempPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
  tempPreviewLayer.frame = frame;

  UIView* tempView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [tempView.layer addSublayer:tempPreviewLayer];
  tempView.frame = frame;

  [tempPreviewLayer autorelease];
  [tempView autorelease];
  return tempView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to handsomely follow all rotations. This is how I did it (`overlayView` is just a view that happens to have the correct bounds). It only animates without a hick-up when you place your calls to super exactly where they are in the code:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    if ([[[self previewLayer] connection] isVideoOrientationSupported])
    {
        [[[self previewLayer] connection] setVideoOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
    }
}

- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect layerRect = [[self overlayView] bounds];
    [[self previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
    [[self previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                                 CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];

    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration: duration];
}
```

Comment: Drawback: for me, this solution is not enough. The snapshots I make from this camera preview, when loaded into an UIImageView, are in the original orientation of the camera preview. I will search for a separate solution for that, maybe pose a new question...

Comment: Next drawback: boss says this is way not handsome enough. So we do as they all do, fix the camera preview in portrait and rotate the controls listening to UIDeviceOrientation changing...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CATransform3DMakeRotation` which is meant for Layers, like it has been mentioned on the comments:

For instance:

```
float degreesToRotate = 90.0; //Degrees you want to rotate
self.previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(degreesToRotate / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

In my case, being "self.previewLayer" the layer to rotate. Have in mind that you should clip it to it's container view's bounds afterwards:

```
self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

.
.
.

**EDIT:** If you are going to rotate as a result of the device being rotated (`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`) you should make the transformation like this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    //**Perform Transformation here**
    [CATransaction commit];
```

This way, the layer will rotate as the view does.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (tookFirstPicture)
        return;

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        [previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        [previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
    }
    else {
        [previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];
    }
}
```

Comment: This's been deprecated in iOS 6. Use `AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:`

Answer (score 0):

In swift I use:

```
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    if !UIDevice.currentDevice().model.contains("Simulator") {
        if (toInterfaceOrientation == .Portrait) {
            prevLayer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 0, 1)
        } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == .LandscapeLeft) {
            prevLayer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI)/2, 0, 0, 1)
        } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == .LandscapeRight) {
            prevLayer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI)/2, 0, 0, 1)
        }
        prevLayer?.frame = self.scanView.frame
    }
}
```

Comment: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation was deprecated in iOS8

Comment: Can you please provide an alternative solution?

Comment: Take a look at Kal's answer. The best solution is to not rotate it.

Answer (score 0):

After examining [Apple Example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app), I have figured out how to disable the rotation of your `videoPreviewLayer` in iOS 11 and later. (not sure if the same works for older version)

Simply set the `clipToBounds = false` on the `UIView` of your `videoPreviewLayer`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Since `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is a CALayer, then any changes will be animated, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html. To stop the animation just `[previewLayer removeAllAnimations]`.