# How to handle a device rotation for AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, swiftui, avfoundation, screen-orientation

I have a simple camera preview implementation:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CameraView: View {
    @StateObject var model = CameraModel()
    var body: some View {
        CameraPreview(camera: model)
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Color.clear
                    .frame(height: 0)
                    .background(Material.bar)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
            .onAppear() {
                model.check()
            }
    }
}

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var camera: CameraModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        camera.preview.frame = view.frame
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        camera.start()
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct CameraView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CameraView()
    }
}

class CameraModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    @Published var alert = false
    @Published var preview: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    func check() {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
            setUp()
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                if status {
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
            break
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func setUp() {
        do {
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func start() {
        self.session.startRunning()
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't handle screen rotations:

[image: Screenshot]

I found similar topics, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016963/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-smooth-orientation-rotation), but I am a noobie in iOS development, I can't even understand where to put this solution. I've checked neither `View`, nor `UIViewRepresentable` have such methods to override.

How to handle screen rotation in `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working variant with video rotation based on [Dscyre Scotti'es answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71702670/3253896):

```
struct CameraView: View {
    @StateObject var model = CameraModel()
    var body: some View {
        CameraPreview(camera: model)
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Color.clear
                    .frame(height: 0)
                    .background(Material.bar)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: [.top, .horizontal])
            .onAppear() {
                model.check()
            }
    }
}

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var camera: CameraModel
    
    class LayerView: UIView {
        var parent: CameraPreview! = nil
        
        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            // To disable default animation of layer. You can comment out those lines with `CATransaction` if you want to include
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            layer.sublayers?.forEach({ layer in
                layer.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            })
            self.parent.camera.rotate(orientation: UIDevice.current.orientation)
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = LayerView()
        view.parent = self
        camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        camera.preview.frame = view.frame
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        camera.start()
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct CameraView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CameraView()
    }
}

class CameraModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    @Published var alert = false
    @Published var preview: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    func check() {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
            setUp()
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                if status {
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
            break
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func setUp() {
        do {
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func start() {
        self.session.startRunning()
    }
    
    func rotate(orientation: UIDeviceOrientation) {
        let videoConnection = self.preview.connection
        switch orientation {
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
        case .landscapeLeft:
            videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeRight:
            videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
        case .faceDown:
            videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
        default:
            videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. I had to remove `@Published` from `var preview: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!` in `CameraModel`, because of the warning `Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update layer frame in rotation, you need to create custom `UIView` and override `layoutSubviews()`. Inside `layoutSubviews()`, you need to update frame for sublayers.

The code will be as below.

```swift
struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var camera: CameraModel
    
    class LayerView: UIView {
        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            // To disable default animation of layer. You can comment out those lines with `CATransaction` if you want to include
            CATransaction.begin() 
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            layer.sublayers?.forEach({ layer in
                layer.frame = frame
            })
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = LayerView()
        camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.frame = view.frame
        camera.preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        camera.session.startRunning()
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I have just changed one line `layer.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds` to fill all screen but it helped! Unfortunately, camera image is still not rotated, just fill screen.